# Create, Edit, Delete a Virtual Directory, Website and Application in PowerShell

Tags: iis, powershell

I created and deleted the virtual directory using PowerShell, which works fine.

But how can I modify the name and port path ?

Answer (score 5):

Note this will only work on Windows 7 or Win2k8R2

```
Import-Module webadministration
```

That will import all the commands required to modify IIS websites , at this point you have 2 options , you can make the changes my navigating to IIS:\ and using set-Item etc or you can call

```
 (Get-Website)
```

Which will list all your websites on the server , you can either index them manually to change the settings i.e  (Get-Website)[0] will allow you to change the settings of the first site. Use  (Get-Website) | Get-Member to get more details about the list of commands you can use.

Comment: +1. Just spent two hours investigating why everybody seems to happily use "get-item "iis:\sites\" and alike, but I get "A drive with the name 'iis' does not exist" instead. Doh :)

Comment: if Import_Module doesn't work first time try : set-executionpolicy remotesigned  then restart powershell and try again

Comment: Also make sure to run PowerShell as an Admin.

Comment: Try `import-module WebAdministration` (IIS7.5+) followed by "Set-Location IIS:\"

Answer (score 1):

This [article](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/433/powershell-snap-in-creating-web-sites-web-applications-virtual-directories-and-application-pools/) covers the basics of using PowerShell to work with IIS bits

There is also a Web Administration (IIS) Provider covered [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee909471%28v=WS.10%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I have a set of scripts for doing stuff like this which you may find useful. See https://github.com/alastairtree/deploy-websites-with-powershell

With that you can then do something like this:

```
CreateVirtualDirectory.ps1 [WebsiteName] [FolderName] [PhysicalPath] ([domain\user] [password])
```

I imagine adding port to that would be easy enough - feel free to fork it ;-)